# MP4 not displaying on LOCAL Apache via HTML5 tag, but webm - yes?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to test HTML5 video on XAMPP (local/Intranet Apache running on WinXP) with the following code(s)..

```
<video width="590px" height="332px" controls="controls">
<source src="http://localhost/work( this is website root folder)/broadband/video/Test_video.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

Fact 1: On Chrome, HTML5 .webm & .mp4 plays like a charm.

Fact 2: On Opera 34 and FireFox 43, .webm works. But, I cannot get .mp4 playing at all, on both FF & Opera. FF says "unsupported format OR bad MIME type" and controls on both players/browsers are freezed.

Fact 3: No MIME types are specified, anywhere. Not mp4, not even a webm. Not specified in .htacces, not specified in conf/mime.types file also. Nothing otherwise happens even if I do specify what I tried already. But no matter that, .webm format - runs on both "problematic" browsers, being specified or not.

mp4 Video file data: H.264/AAC, resolution 656 x 370

ps: I didnt tested this issue online because first I would like running it on XAMPP.

I would like to rely completely on MP4 format (without webm and ogv formats/backups) so I hope someone knows fix for this or at least.. has some clue. Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

There simply is no way to force support for mp4. HTML audio and video elements rely on browser support, it is baked into the browser. If the users browser does not support it your out of luck.

Here is the best straight forward tutorial and reasoning I have come across explaining this: [HTML5 video element](http://blainerobertson.net/content/?content=487).

Proper HTML5 is to use the source tag and give the browser backup options. On a live production site you should be doing this. I know it can be annoying for testing sites but in that case just use Chrome for mp4 support well you test it.

**EDIT**
The only option you have is showing a link that allows the mp4 to be downloaded if the browser can not play the format you used.

**UPDATE**
The link I originally added is suffering from link rot. I am adding the main content below in case it happens again. If the link rots again and you want the full article search for *HTML5 VIDEO INTRODUCTION* by Blaine Robertson.

> In the past, HTML relied on third-party tools such as Flash to place and run video inside of a web page. Fortunately, HTML5 and the modern browsers that support it make that a thing of the past. Now, browsers can support video natively, which makes things far more convenient for developers and site visitors. You can learn much more of the official information about HTML5 video at the W3C wiki reference at http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/video)
>
> As with audio formats, different browsers support different video formats. That makes it cumbersome for developers because **instead of creating a single video, you will have to create three versions of the video file** using differing formats: MP4, OGV and WebM.

[image: Browsers and formats chart]

Comment: Dont get me wrong but all this stuff is a huge shame for browsers vendors industry. Not just this question, not just this problem. I spent 2 days reading all around the web reading about this new "html5 feature". They cannot get 3 simple formats up and running in their cool and fancy software. Maybe Ill just place a background image in a video area for mobile users saying - "people wake up and find Flash in order to play a simple video without any (update) headaches". Thx for help anyway Blizz Ill paste an update on this..

Comment: You could always default to flash as well? But to be honest, first world problems. There is a TON of things that browsers need to account for and at the end of the day how hard is it for you to run your mp4 video through a converter and have multiple versions to fall back on? That is true web development; even accounting for assistive technologies trying to render your site. Not to mention that we all use our browsers for free. None of us pay anything for them. Its not our right to have everything we want in them and to demand it now.

Comment: Also, you pointed it out. HTM5 is still considered new. Give it time to fully saturate the market (yes this can take a few years). XHTML5 as it is being called hasn't even be finalized as a standard yet for example. At least we have a video element to work on now.

Comment: Fact is I do run Flash runtime for 4 years and hey, I wanted to "advance a bit" and do a favor to mobile users to watch some videos (lol)..Just this month it is expected for domain to upload at least one hundred videos. Professionals should have NO TIME to deal with (such) bugs in browsers, to convert one file in 3 different formats being browsers free or paid. Visitors nerves & stress are free man, our work is free man, not theirs. For a simple 5min thing we must spend 7 days just for a one simple tag.

Comment: I am running right now (and for years) on a 12.16 Opera browser. I think that explains quite much what non stop today browsers updates - really are. It is obvious that mp4 is revolutionary format, for 10 years whole Internet became full of .flv video which is extraordinary format also, but no.. ogv and webm fallbacks are newest update. Think about it. Nothing 4 you Blizz, just wanna send my 50 cents to browser vendors. PS: 12.16 opera has its own hmtl5 player inside and thats quite old browser. Few years? At least 10 if you ask me. Guess I came to early into H5..